# Problema em relacionamento com EF6 (Auto-Relacionamento e Classe Associativa)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Preciso saber se o meu auto relacionamento e a minha classe associativa estão criadas de forma correta conforme o modelo original feito no Diagrama do SQL Server.

**Modelo Original - SQL Server**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu modelo no Power Tools**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Classe Região**

```
[Table("Regiao")]
public class Regiao
{
    [Key]
    public long RegiaoID { get; set; }
    public string RegiaoDescricao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Territorio> Territorios { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe Território**

```
[Table("Territorio")]
public class Territorio
{
    [Key]
    public long TerritorioID { get; set; }
    public string TerritorioDescricao { get; set; }

    public long RegiaoID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RegiaoID")]
    public virtual Regiao Regiao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TerritorioEmpregado> TerritorioEmpregados { get; set; }

}
```

**Classe Empregado**

```
[Table("Empregado")]
public class Empregado
{
    [Key]
    public long EmpregadoID { get; set; }
    public string PrimeiroNome { get; set; }
    public string UltimoNome { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string TituloDeCortesia { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataContratacao { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Regiao { get; set; }
    public string CodigoPostal { get; set; }
    public string Pais { get; set; }
    public string TelefoneResidencial { get; set; }
    public string Extensao { get; set; }
    public string Notas { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TerritorioEmpregado> TerritorioEmpregados { get; set; }

    public virtual Empregado Empregado1 { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe Associativa TerritorioEmpregado**

```
public class TerritorioEmpregado
{
    [Key]
    public long TerritorioEmpregadoID { get; set; }
    public long TerritorioID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TerritorioID")]
    public virtual Territorio Territorio { get; set; }

    public long EmpregadoID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmpregadoID")]
    public virtual Empregado Empregado2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se sua intenção é usar uma tabela associativa, você deve criar a mesma e realizar as devidas associações.

Neste caso, você precisaria criar a entidade **TerritorioEmpregados**. Como seu modelo **SQL** Mostra, ela que será a ligação entre **Territórios** e **Empregados**.

Essa entidade ficaria assim:

```
 public class TerritorioEmpregado
    {
        [Key]
        public int TerriTorioEmpregadoId { get; set; }

        public int TerritorioId { get; set; }
        public int EmpregadoId { get; set; }

        public virtual Territorio Territorio { get; set; }
        public virtual Empregado Empregado { get; set; }
    }
```

Lembrando que isso é apenas um exemplo. Você pode alterar-lá da forma que melhor lhe atender. Mas ela deverá estar em seu código.

Feito isso, você já terá essa associação que deseja. Porém, sua entidade **Empregado** possui essa associação:

```
 public long TerritorioID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TerritorioID")]
    public virtual Territorio Territorio { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Empregado> Empregados1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Empregado Empregados2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Territorio> Territorios { get; set; }
```

Isso torna-se desnecessário. Nesta parte você está dizendo que seu empregado possui 1 território, 1 empregado, uma lista de Territórios e uma lista de empregados. Creio que não seja isso que você deseja.

Altere para isso:

```
 public virtual ICollection<TerritorioEmpregado> TerritorioEmpregado { get; set; }
 public virtual Empregado Empregados2 { get; set; }
```

Neste caso, você está dizendo que um empregado possui uma lista de **TerritórioEmpregado** e um relacionamento com ele mesmo.

Fazendo isso, seu modelo ficará assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Randrade, minha classe Território depois das modificações ficou com propriedade de navegação a mais, não sei se foi porque você fez ao contrário o relacionamento entre Território e Região. Na lógica, uma região pode ter vários territórios, a região seria: Sul, Sudeste, Centro Oeste etc. Outra dúvida que fiquei foi em relação a nomenclatura das chaves estrangeiras, não consegui deixar com o prefixo FK, como o seu modelo, o seu ficou bem melhor. Gostaria que você avaliasse meu código para ver se fiz algo de errado, a minha pergunta foi editada e a imagem gerada no meu Power Tools foi atualizada.

Comment: @KellySoares não querendo ser "chato", mas será que você poderia retornar à pergunta original e abrir outra pergunta específica? Sua dúvida inicial era em como utilizar uma tabela associativa, e agora está com com duas outras dúvidas derivadas desta resposta. Isso é normal acontecer, mas fica melhor para a comunidade ter as duas perguntas com dúvidas diferentes, ao editar a mesma.

Comment: @KellySoares Eu ficarei feliz em responder suas dúvidas sem problemas. Mas ficaria mais fácil para quem procurar sobre, se estiver melhor organizado.

Comment: Desculpe Randrade, é porque aqui não permite incluir imagens em comentários, por isso editei a pergunda para confirmar as alterações que você sugeriu, eu não guardei a imagem anterior para colocar novamente. Posso mudar a pergunta se isso resolver.

Comment: Alterei a dúvida, espero que tenha melhorado o erro que cometi. Obrigada novamente!

Comment: @KellySoares você não cometeu nenhum erro. Isso é normal e acontece com frequência. Eu apenas acho melhor deixar tudo organizadinho. Mas abra outra pergunta com a dúvida, que respondo para você com o maior prazer.

Comment: Randrade, você me ajudou uma vez a fazer carregar scripts no ASP.NET MVC, será que você consegue descobrir o erro nesse outro post que abri? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89144/erro-ao-criar-janela-modal-com-jquery-em-asp-net-mvc